# iOS momentum scrolling on scrollable div with fixed positioned child element

Tags: ios, css, web-applications

I'm working on an angular webapp that has a main navbar and several views that each has its own sub-navbar.

Each view is maintained within a scrollable div, and only a single div is visible at any given time.

These views are hardware accelerated using the 'will-change' CSS property, and momentum scrolling is enabled using the -webkit-overflow-scrolling CSS property.

Inside each of these DIVs there is a sub-navbar that is fixed positioned after the main navbar.

Everything works as expected except for one annoying glitch, on iPad/iPhone the sub-navbar keeps bouncing out and then into its position.

[Here's a pen](https://codepen.io/niro78/pen/ZyEdNp) illustrating the problem. Notice those glitches on that yellow SUB MENU when you scroll on iPad/iPhone...

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main_header">
      MAIN MENU
    </div>
    <div class="views-container">
      <div class="view">
        <div class="view-header test">
          SUB MENU
        </div>
        <div>
          CONTENT
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

.main_header {
  background-color:green;
  position: fixed;
  top:0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.views-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 18px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.view {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  will-change: opacity;
}

.view-header {
  background-color:yellow;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

I've scoured the web in search for a solution but came up with nothing thus far.
Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (See bottom of answer for codepen solution)

Testing on my iPhone I could get the sub-menu to not act up by changing from:

```
<body>
    <div class="main_header">
      MAIN MENU
    </div>
    <div class="views-container">
      <div class="view"> <-- move this div below "view-header test"
        <div class="view-header test">
          SUB MENU
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
```

to:

```
<body>
    <div class="main_header">
      MAIN MENU
    </div>
    <div class="views-container">
      <div class="view-header test">
          SUB MENU
      </div>
      <div class="view"> <-- move to here
        <div class="container-fluid">
```

It seems like the `view` class's css causes the sub menu to try and scroll on iphones and ipads.

Let me know if this works for you

EDIT:

Another solution would be to mess around with the css. Basically your `.view` class contains your .view-header class and therefore with content of the `.view-header` will also be influenced by the `.view` class. One solution might be to make a `.view-body` class where you place any code relevant to the body of the view which you don't want to influence your header. then do

```
<div class="view">
   <div class="view-header">
      header content. probably does not need to be scroll-able
   </div>
   <div class="view-body">
      body content. probably needs to be scroll-able 
   </div
</div>
```

DOUBLE EDIT:

Forked your code and made the changes that I recommended. It works perfectly now on my iPhone. Hope this helps!
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgWOGx

Comment: The first solution is irrelevant as the view-header is dynamic and has to be contained within the view. The second solution looks and works great, unfortunately I presented here a simplified version of my case so it won't be so easy incorporating such a change, but I'll give it a try as it seems like the only viable solution. Thanks!